# java 8 method reference into lambda

Tags: java, sorting, compiler-errors, java-8, comparator

I have this code that I try to convert the method reference ("String::length") into equivalent lambda expression.

```
 Stream<String> s = Stream.of("hello", "your name", "welcome", "z");

 List<String> list = s.sorted((a, b) -> Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).compare(a, b)).collect(toList());

 // List<String> list = s.sorted((a, b) -> Comparator.comparingInt( p -> {return ((String)p).length();}).compare(a, b)).collect(toList());
```

The only way it works is outlined in the commented line. I need to cast the argument "p".

Seems like at compile time it specifies the type of the argument "p" to be an Object if I use the lambda expression and I need to cast explicitly. See below:

```
<Object> Comparator<Object> java.util.Comparator.comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super Object> keyExtractor)
```

When I use a String::length method reference then at compile time the implicit argument is correctly understood as a String instance. What is so special in this case? See below.

```
<String> Comparator<String> java.util.Comparator.comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super String> keyExtractor)
```

Comment: This should work too (without cast): `(String p) -> p.length()`.

Comment: `(a, b) -> Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).compare(a, b)` = `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)::compare` = `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)`

Comment: I think what OP is asking is why in `p -> p.length()` the `p` variable is not recognized as `String` by Java compiler.

Comment: @tsolakp: yes you are correct.

Comment: @Khanna11. I think it is because that call to `comparingInt` does not specify what type will be passed to it and by default it assumes an Object. To give a hint to compiler you need to either use method reference, my previous commented syntax or this: `Comparator.<String>comparingInt( p -> p.length() )`.

Comment: @tsolakp: I think you might be up to something here when you mention "hint". Hopefully that is documented someplace.

Comment: @tsolakp or simply `Comparator.comparingInt((String p) ->  p.length())....`

Comment: @tsolakp: perhaps you can put that in an answer so I can tick it.

Comment: That unnessary indirection confuses the compiler just like us. Actually, it's the chaining of method invocations. When you use, `s.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.length())) .collect(toList())`, there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full lambda for `String::length` is:

```
(String p) -> p.length()
```

It can also be written using a block, but it's more common to use the simpler expression above:

```
(String p) -> { return p.length(); }
```

If the compiler can infer the type, you *may* omit it:

```
p -> p.length()
```

But you're using this:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.length())
```

That is all the compiler sees when it needs to infer type of `p`. So, what is `p`? No idea, the compiler says. So you must explicitly specify the type:

```
// Explicit type in parameter list
Comparator.comparingInt((String p) -> p.length())

// Explicit type on generic type parameter
Comparator.<String>comparingInt(p -> p.length())

// You can do both, but why would you?
Comparator.<String>comparingInt((String s) -> s.length())

// Explicit type of referenced method
Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
```

Notice that none of the code uses casts. The above is all type-safe, unlike the code you wrote with a cast. Do not use cast!

All 4 calls above returns a `Comparator<String>`. That comparator can be used to e.g. sort a `List<String>`, but will give compile error if you try to sort any other type of list.

When you cast like this:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(p -> ((String) p).length())
```

it returns a `Comparator<Object>`, which means that you could give that comparator when trying to sort any type of list, e.g. a `List<Integer>`. It will compile, but fail at runtime. The use of a cast has made to code not type-safe. As I said, don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an anonymous lambda that would implement the functional `Comparator` interface, just use a straight-up Comparator:

```
List<String> list = 
    s.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).collect(toList());
```

Comment: I know that. The question is why the "p" is not recognized as a String.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT About why the type of `p` is not inferred.**

The type of `p` is not automatically inferred to be `String` for very much the same reasons why it is not inferred in the following example:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.length).compare(a, b);
```

Here, it fails with the message that `Object` does not have method `length`. To understand why, consider a (very rough approximation of) the abstract syntax tree of this expression:

```
                                                                  Apply
                                                                 /     \
                                                                /       \
                                                               /         \
                                                              /           \
                                             _______________ /             \__
                                            /                                 \
                                           /                                   \
                                          /                                     \
                                  MemberSelection                             ArgumentList(2)
                                  /             \______                       /             \
                                 /                     \                     /               \
                           Apply                      compare              a: String     b: String
                     _____/     \______
                    /                  \
                   /                    \
          MemberSelection             Lambda
          /          |                 |    \
         /           |                 |     \
Comparator     comparingInt       Variable    MemberSelection
                                       |          /      \
                                       p         p       length
```

As you can see, the type information about `String` is completely in the right part of the AST, whereas the variable binder `p` and the entire closure are on a left branch of the AST.

It just happens to be that the type inference algorithm always works locally in top-down fashion. Once it descends into the left subtree and fails to infer the type of `p`, it will not walk back up the tree and search in the right subtree for additional hints. That would be too complicated to implement, and the further the type-checker would walk away from the problematic binder `p`, the less clear the error messages about failed type inference would become. The type inference algorithm does not make any attempts to typecheck the entire program globally.

---

You don't need the `(a, b) -> ...` part at all, the `Comparator.compare(...)` *already* produces a comparator:

```
List<String> list = s.
  sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).
  collect(toList());
```

does what you probably wanted.

Comment: I know that. The question is why the "p" is not recognized as a String.

Comment: @Khanna111 I've added a detailed discussion about why the type inference algorithm fails in this case.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I understand what you mean by "left to right", but this is a pretty misleading characterization of how Java's type inference works.   But you are correct that _in this case_ -- an invocation expression `a.b()`, where the type of `a` has type variables -- we cannot do member selection for `b()` before we know those variables.  So when the receiver in a chain is a generic method invocation _and_ we cannot infer those type variables solely from the method arguments, we get stuck.

Comment: @BrianGoetz The above sketch is not an exact representation of what's going on inside the javac. I'm even pretty sure that the real AST does not contain any Apply nodes at all, because Java is not an FP language, so `Comparator.comparingInt` will not be considered a function. It's rather a hypothetical AST for a hypothetical compiler of a Java-like language. That's not the point. The point is that `p` and `String` end up in vastly different subtrees no matter how you represent it, and the typechecker fails to infer type of `p` before it even sees the `String` in another subtree.

Comment: @BrianGoetz in the previous comment, by "Java-like" I mean that the typechecker will not come back from the "left" subtree with some weird universally quantified `forall a . Length<a> => Comparator<a>`, and then happily continue the search for an instance of some `Length<String>`-"typeclass" or something like that.